# How to use existing Scala with Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, homebrew

I already have `brew install scala` - I am able to run Scala via command line. After that I installed IntelliJ version 2016.1.3

While installation process of IntelliJ, I was asked to install Scala plugin but i clicked no - because I already have Scala installed

Now I am trying to figure out where exactly we can create a Scala application with the use of my existing Scala installed. How and where in the IntelliJ can I set this up? I can only see Java projects available to be created.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The Scala you have installed is a completely different thing from the IDEA Scala plugin.

The Scala plugin is what you need to handle Scala projects, editing Scala files, etc. in IDEA. The command-line Scala is just the compiler and the standard library, it doesn't know anything about IDEA.

Also, for the command line you should install [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/index.html) instead of working directly with the Scala compiler unless you want to handle dependencies, classpaths, etc. manually (you don't).

Comment: Okay thanks - will uninstall the Scala brew and will install via IntelliJ

Comment: As mentioned, I do recommend getting familiar with SBT as well. IDEA Scala plugin works with SBT projects very well.

Comment: Yes I just installed SBT via IntelliJ - now doing a SBT refresh and its downloading some stuff. Thank you this is a good intro to Scala

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create Scala application using IntelliJ IDEA, you will need to install the Scala Plugin.

**Step 1: Open IntelliJ Preferences or Settings**

**On Mac:**

- Open IntelliJ IDEA.
- Then click on the menu item **IntelliJ IDEA** and select **Preferences**.

**On Windows:**

- Open IntelliJ IDEA.
- On the bottom right corner of the **Welcome to IntelliJ** screen, select **Configure**.

**Step 2: Find and install Scala Plugin**

- After opening the **Preferences** or **Settings** screen from Step 1, click on the **Plugins** section on the left panel.
- Then click on the **Install JetBrains plugin…** button.
- This opens another window which has a **Search box** on the top left corner. Type in **Scala** in the search box and this will list the Scala plugin which you need to install.
- Hit the **Install** button to kick off the installation.
- Do not forget to **Restart IntelliJ** following the install.

And Voila! You should now be able to create Scala projects in IntelliJ.

For further instructions on how to install Scala plugin in IntelliJ, you can follow the instructions from [www.allaboutscala.com](http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-1-getting-familiar-intellij-ide/scala-environment-setup-install-scala-plugin-intellij/)